Cumulative Probability Function as a Piecewise Function
Let $X$ be a discrete random variable. You're given the cumulative probability function : $F(x)=\lfloor{x}\rfloor\frac{x}{8}$, evaluating $x\in [1,3)$. Then, the function can be written as a piecewise function:
$$ F(x) =
\begin{cases}
0,  & x\lt 1\\
\frac{x}{8}, & 1\le x\lt 2\\
\frac{2x}{8}+\frac{x}{8}  &2\le x\lt 3\\
1,  & 3\le x
\end{cases}$$
Originally, I need to find $\Bbb{E}[X]$ and $\text{Var}(X)$ but I don't get how to correctly calculate the accumulation in the interval $2\le x\lt 3$, can you explain that to me? I think I have a conceptual misunderstanding of what that is, because before I got to that function, I tried this:  $\frac{2}{8}\int_{2}^{3} x dx-\frac{1}{8}\int_{1}^{2} xdx$, for the same interval and wich returns $\frac{5}{16}$, so it was $\frac{2x}{8}+\frac{5}{16}$. I don't get it yet. Can you help me?

This does not make sense. $\lim_{x \uparrow 3} F(x) = {9 \over 8} > 1$.

How is it? Should I include the case where $3\le x$?

Ok, I think I starting to see why. But what about the second condition?

I am starting to suspect that the function that you are given is not CDF but pdf

Seems like the function you have been given is not "Cummulative" Distribution function but just probability density function (possibly mixed). So the function will be as follows in different intervals:
f(x) = \begin{cases} 
          0 & x\leq 0 \\
          0 & 0\leq x < 1 \\
          \frac{x}{8} & 1 \leq x < 2 \\
          \frac{2x}{8}& 2 \leq x < 3 
       \end{cases}
So $\mathbb{E}(X)$ = $1 \cdot \frac{1}{8}$ + $\int_{1}^{2}x \cdot \frac{x}{8}$+  $2 \cdot \frac{5}{16}$ + $\int_{2}^{3} x \cdot \frac{2x}{8}$

Actually I was given only the formula, I gave the piecewise function

is everything clear now? if you got any doubts lemme know

Can you expand on your answer, please?
